# How to listen for Telegram Bot errors? (Google App Script + Webhooks)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling, webhooks, telegram-bot

I have developed a fully functional Telegram Bot with Google App Script that uses Webhooks to read and write into a Google Spreadsheet.

Although the bot is stable, sometimes it crashes due to specific user interaction like pressing buttons too fast or making the bot send too many messages in a short amount of time.

The [Error Handling section of the Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors) mentions that errors are returned in [rpc_error](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages#rpc-error) constructors, but there is no reference to any method that can be used to listen for any error that may occur.

I want to handle these errors but the only way I am aware is to listen for errors on each API request.

Here is an example of how I am handling an error right now:

```
function editKeyboardMessage(buttonArray) {
  var id = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("inline_form_chat_id");
  var message_id = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("inline_form_message_id");
  var keyboardMarkup = {"inline_keyboard": buttonArray};
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
       method: "editMessageReplyMarkup",
       chat_id: String(id),
       message_id: Number(message_id),
       parse_mode: "HTML",
       reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboardMarkup)
     }
   };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "/", data)
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode()
  handleErrors(responseCode)
}
```

However, it seems unpractical to do this on all requests types and it doesn't allow complete error handling (like the ones that happen independently of requests, such as message flooding).

The expected outcome would be to properly handle all incoming errors in just one place.
Is there a way to listen for all bot errors with something similar to the `doPost(e)` function that is used to listen for updates?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are currently talking on Telegram - it might be helpful for others.
The conversation started at https://t.me/BotTalk/105298

---

`tl;dr` you need to do error handling on your end. If you don't use a library, try checking each response from Telegram after sending out a request for errors. If there are errors, handle them accordingly.